# How to add Google map with WordPress without using plugin

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

How can we add a Google map with WordPress.

Consider my coordinates

```
<longitude>17.549062233809</longitude>
<latitude>40.68792578497581</latitude>
```

Please can anybody give me an idea.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a static map for those coordinates then you can type **40.687926,17.549062** into http://maps.google.com/ and get the map embed code, which is:

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=40.687926,17.549062&amp;aq=&amp;sll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;sspn=36.231745,70.136719&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=40.687173,17.550865&amp;spn=1.085161,2.191772&amp;z=9&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

Just copy and paste that anywhere in your blog.

Otherwise use the other suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Embed a map using [google maps api for javascript](http://code.google.com/intl/el-GR/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/) and assuming you give the coordinates because you want to place a marker check [here](http://code.google.com/intl/el-GR/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Markers)